# Writing data on formatted xlsx sheets using XLConnect

Tags: r, csv, xlconnect

I can use the split and then the below to split my dataframe by column values (DF$Name) and pop them out into individual CSV files.

```
DFNames<- split(DF, DF$Name)
DF= read.csv("~/Downloads/DataDownload_2012.csv")
for (name in levels(DF$Name)){
  tmp=subset(DF,Name==name)
  fn=paste('Expenses/',gsub(' ','',name),sep='', ".CSV")
  write.csv(tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

But, I would love to pop them out into pre-formatted excel files. I can use XLConnect and the below to pop out my dataframe into an excel file, but i cant do it to multiple files based on the column variable.

```
    DataFormatted<- loadWorkbook("Income.xlsx")
    xldf = readWorksheet(DataFormatted, sheet = getSheets(DataFormatted)[1])
    sheet_name <- "Data"
    renameSheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb)[1], newName = sheet_name)
    writeWorksheet(wb,xldf,sheet=getSheets(wb)[1],startRow=2,header=F)
    saveWorkbook(wb,'income_data.xlsx')
```

Help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you need help writing a for-loop in the second block which is similar to the first block?  Does `xldf` have a `Name` column which you need to loop over, and you'd create several spreadsheets?

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I need.